# How can I get rid of offset on head-rule?

Tags: header-footer

My headrule is offset throught my thesis. It looks like this:

[image]

I found a MWE that displays the same behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps


\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%

    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{20pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{20pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{5pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{20pt}
}


\newpagestyle{main}{
\setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
\sethead{\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}% left
        {}%                                 center
        {\thesection\ \sectiontitle}%       right
}

\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
\section{A section}

This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 

\subsection{A subsection}
dsd
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

I realized that the issue is caused by the command \expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter. If I remove it the issue disappears. However I cannot remove it as I need it for spacing equations.

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've lost a bit of the code you're copying:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
  \normalsize
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{20pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{20pt}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{5pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{20pt}%
}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
  \sethead{\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}% left
          {}%                                 center
          {\thesection\ \sectiontitle}%       right
}

\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 

\section{A section}

This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 

\subsection{A subsection}
dsd
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

A `\normalsize` (that's expanded at redefinition time) was missing (and also some `%` were).

[image]

A simpler strategy would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{20pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{20pt}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{5pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{20pt}%
}
```

and the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you replace

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
```

with

```
\AtBeginDcoument{%
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{20pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{20pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{5pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{20pt}
}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
\setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
\sethead{\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}% left
        {}%                                 center
        {\thesection\ \sectiontitle}%       right
}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction.

\section{A section}
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. 
This is the introduction. This is the introduction.

\subsection{A subsection}
dsd

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This wouldn't change `\normalsize` and the settings would not be honored whenever the command is (implicitly) issued.

Comment: @egreg - Isn't `\normalsize` -- actually, \normal-everything... -- executed automatically upon entering the `document` environment? Hence, there should be no need to run the command separately. Plus, I can't conceive of a reason for why the four length parameters would have to be reset more than once.